# MvvmCross Android binding in preferences

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross

Is there any way to use MvvmCross binding with Android preferences? I mean something like this:

```
<PreferenceScreen
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <EditTextPreference
      android:title="Name"
      android:key="NameKey"
      android:summary="Input your name"
      local:MvxBind="Title Name; Enabled NameIsEnabled"/>
  </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I need binding, because I want dynamically modify preferences and localize titles and summaries. I'm currently using this [Andrei Nitescu's idea](http://enginecore.blogspot.fi/2013/09/localization-in-xamarin-mvvmcross_18.html) for localization. Can I do this for example by implementing my own BindablePreferenceFragment or BindableEditTextPreference?

Comment: I am working on bindings for preferences: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/pull/91 but don't expect it anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

Why not bind to a property like so?

```
SpinnerItem _selectedNumberPlayers;
public SpinnerItem SelectedNumberPlayers
{
    get { return _selectedNumberPlayers; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedNumberPlayers != value)
        {
            _selectedNumberPlayers = value;

            SettingsPreferences.SelectedNumberPlayers = _selectedNumberPlayers.Index;

            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedNumberPlayers);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the binding:

```
<Mvx.MvxSpinner
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_spinner"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource NumberPlayers; SelectedItem SelectedNumberPlayers"
    android:id="@+id/SelectedTopPlayersSpinner" />
```

Comment: But how to adapt this with Android preferences?

Comment: In the property I update my android preferences directly: SettingsPreferences.SelectedNumberPlayers = _selectedNumberPlayers.Index;